# Get the index out of AnyObject list of items IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, anyobject

parsed is an NsDictionary and I am pulling the balances out of it via

if let findbalances: AnyObject = parsed["balances"]

which gives me a list of balances in AnyObject  format

```
(
    {
    "available_amount" = 133519;
    currency = AUD;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 7854;
    currency = CAD;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 88581;
    currency = EUR;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 0;
    currency = GBP;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 63618;
    currency = INR;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 375;
    currency = NZD;
},
    {
    "available_amount" = 0;
    currency = TRY; 
},
    {

    "available_amount" = 2918958;
    currency = USD;

}
)
```

I know that

```
let whatCurrency = (findbalances[7]["currency"] as! String)
```

=USD  But how do I find  that value [7]  if the  amount of  objects  changes?

I want to match on USD

I tried

```
let  defaultcurr = "USD"
let findUSD = findbalances.indexOfObject(defaultcurr)
```

but that gave me  9223372036854775807

How do I just  find 7

Comment: Why not just loop through it?

Comment: looping through it may work  - what I then want to do is  use the values from that row.  (where currency == USD)  so how would I find that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9223372036854775807` is `NSNotFound`.

You can use a closure as argument of `indexOf`

```
let  defaultcurr = "USD"
let findUSDIndex = findbalances.indexOf { ($0["currency"] as! String) == defaultcurr }
```

Or you can filter the entire row

```
let findUSD = findbalances.filter { ($0["currency"] as! String) == defaultcurr }.first
```

`indexOfObject` seems to be using `NSArray`. Don't do that. Use Swift native `Array` and cast your collection object to `[[String:AnyObject]]` :

```
if let findbalances = parsed["balances"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] { ...
```

Comment: Value of type AnyObject  has no member IndexOf  which is  why I used indexofObject  and If I substitute index of object in there  I get a  Segmentation Fault fail

Comment: That's why I suggested to cast your `AnyObject` to something more meaningful / helpful for the compiler -> `as! [[String:AnyObject]]`

Comment: PS: I edited the answer according to your new information.

Comment: Excellent  - it was the additional  casting that I had not done  and then the rest flowed on  wonderfully!!